# How to use AndroidInjector with subcomponents

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I would like to have following

ApplicationComponent

- subcomponentBlue( modules= ModuleX.class)
- subcomponentRed ( modules= ModuleY.class)

and let's say that I have four Activities A, B, C and D

How to make AndroidInjector works so I can have

- A,B have their own subcomponents that are subcomponents of subcomponentBlue and
- C,D have their own subcomponents that are subcomponents of subcomponentRed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though there isn't a built-in way to do this, you can do so yourself by providing an implementation of [HasActivityInjector](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/HasActivityInjector.java) in your Application. You'll need to recreate some of the niceties that dagger.android provides for you, but that's not all that bad.

Refer to the default implementation for DaggerApplication, [DispatchingAndroidInjector](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/HasActivityInjector.java), which in its `maybeInject` method simply consults the multibinding-built `Map<Class, AndroidInjector.Factory>` to produce an AndroidInjector and call `inject`. If you're following the dagger.android users guide, every AndroidInjector will happen to be a subcomponent and every AndroidInjector.Factory will happen to be a subcomponent builder installed using @ContributesAndroidInjector, but those aren't requirements.

Instead, your Application would contain code that looks kind of like this:

```
public class YourApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {
  // Let's assume your application component calls inject(this) so these
  // @Inject fields are populated, and that you've instantiated some subcomponents
  // that are long-lived. Of course, you can inject your Subcomponent.Builder
  // interfaces instead, if you want a new subcomponent per activity.
  @Inject SubcomponentBlue subcomponentBlue;
  @Inject SubcomponentRed subcomponentRed;

  @Override public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
    // If you can use Java 8 syntax from Android, a lambda would work
    // nicely here, as in "return activity -> { ... };".
    return new AndroidInjector<Activity>() {
      @Override public void inject(Activity activity) {
        if (activity instanceof ActivityA) {
          // HERE'S THE MAGIC: We know that activity is an ActivityA,
          // and that subcomponentBlue has an ActivityA injector, so we
          // perform a cast and then use the Builder to create an
          // injector that we inject with.
          ActivityA aActivity = (ActivityA) activity;
          subcomponentBlue.aInjectorBuilder().create(aActivity).inject(aActivity);
        } elseif (activity instanceof ActivityB) { // ...
        } elseif (activity instanceof ActivityC) {
          ActivityC cActivity = (ActivityC) activity;
          subcomponentRed.cInjectorBuilder().create(cActivity).inject(cActivity);
        } elseif (activity instanceof ActivityD) { // ...
        } else {
          Exception aTantrum = new IllegalArgumentException("Injector not found");
          throw aTantrum;
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

The above is effective, but pretty verbose. As an alternative, rather than using `@ContributesAndroidInjector`, you can manually bind the Activities into the multibinding Map but accessing them through the subcomponent instead:

```
@Module public class YourApplicationModule {
  @Provides @IntoMap @ActivityKey(ActivityA.class)
  static AndroidInjector.Factory<Activity> provideAInjector(
      SubcomponentBlue subcomponentBlue) {
    // Of course, you can also inject a SubcomponentBlue.Builder and
    // create a new one each time.
    return subcomponentBlue.aInjectorBuilder();
  }

  // Same for B, C, and D.
}
```

Requisite note: In all those cases you're trying to access the injectors for A, B, C, and D, outside of their parent subcomponents "red" and "blue". This implies that you'll need to make the injectors (subcomponent builders) accessible as a part of the public APIs of "red" and "blue", and figure out what those subcomponents' lifecycles will look like. Are they long-lived? Per-Activity? Either way, this isn't a lifecycle that other developers might expect, so be prepared to provide ample documentation.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. It is kind of Pre-login scope of an app and Post-login scope of the app.